# Mudar de fragment com clique no button que está dentro da fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, onclick

Tenho uma activity que está com um LinearLayout vazio que serve apenas para 'hospedar' a fragment. Este LinearLayout (chamado layoutFundo) é o argumento da FragmentTransaction para onde uma de várias fragments criada separadamente é 'hospedada'. Isto acontece quando o evento de clique de um dos itens de um navigationDrawer adicionado ao projeto é disparado. Porém, preciso de ajuda no seguinte aspecto: Dentro de uma dessas fragments há um button e eu preciso que esse button, ao ser clicado, direcione para outra fragment que há de ser hospedada no mesmo 'layoutFundo'. Como posso realizar tal procedimento?

Segue código que chama a fragment para o layoutFundo:

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio);

    // Criando o menu
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    // Fragments
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentInicio fragInicio = new FragmentInicio();

        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.layoutFundo, fragInicio, "fragInicio");
        ft.commit();
    }
}

// Este método cria a instância da fragment e ao ser clicada faz um 'replace' para ela ir atrás da pilha

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    FragmentMinhaConta fragMinhaConta = new FragmentMinhaConta();
    FragmentInicio fragInicio = new FragmentInicio();
    FragmentFavoritos fragFavoritos = new FragmentFavoritos();
    FragmentCompras fragCompras = new FragmentCompras();
    FragmentConfiguracoes fragConfiguracoes = new FragmentConfiguracoes();
    FragmentSobre fragSobre = new FragmentSobre();

    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.nav_menu1:
            ft.replace(R.id.layoutFundo, fragMinhaConta, "fragMinhaConta");
            ft.addToBackStack("pilha");
            break;
        case R.id.nav_menu2:
            ft.replace(R.id.layoutFundo, fragInicio, "fragInicio");
            ft.addToBackStack("pilha");
            break;
        case R.id.nav_menu3:
            ft.replace(R.id.layoutFundo, fragFavoritos, "fragFavoritos");
            ft.addToBackStack("pilha");
            break;
        case R.id.nav_menu4:
            ft.replace(R.id.layoutFundo, fragCompras, "fragCompras");
            ft.addToBackStack("pilha");
            break;
        case R.id.nav_menu5:
            ft.replace(R.id.layoutFundo, fragConfiguracoes, "fragConfiguracoes");
            ft.addToBackStack("pilha");
            break;
        case R.id.nav_menu6:
            ft.replace(R.id.layoutFundo, fragSobre, "fragSobre");
            ft.addToBackStack("pilha");
            break;
        case R.id.nav_menu7:
            finish();
            break;
    }
    ft.commit();

    DrawerLayout dl = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    if(dl.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
        dl.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    return false;
}
```

No caso de o usuário clicar no nav_menu1 e o layoutFundo hospedar a fragmentMinhaConta aparecerá dentro da fragment um button, e ao clicar neste button (que está dentro da fragmentMinhaConta) eu preciso que outra fragment (fragmentMinhaContaAtualizar) seja hospedada pelo layoutFundo ao invés dele hospedar a fragmentMinhaConta. Isso para o caso de o usuário ao entrar na fragmentMinhaConta deseje atualizar o seu cadastro.

Segue o código da fragmentMinhaConta com um evento do clique do botão onde deverá chamar a outra fragmentMinhaContaAtualizar:

```
public class FragmentMinhaConta extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment_minhaconta, null);
    Button botao = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnEditarMinhasInformacoes);

    botao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Aqui, deve-se mudar para o outro fragment
            mostrarMsg("Mudar", "Aqui deveria mudar de fragment");
        }
    });
    return (view);
}

public void mostrarMsg(String titulo, String mensagem) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(titulo);
    builder.setMessage(mensagem);
    builder.show();
}
```

}

Ao invés de entrar no método mostrarMsg, eu quero que ele entre em um outro método que sobreescreva aquela mesma fragment pela fragmentMinhaContaAtualizar. Como faço isso?

Answer (score 0):

Vou escrever aqui o que tens que fazer

1ºEnviares a tua atividade para dentro do fragmento, tens que enviar o `this`

2ºCrias uma funcao na tua atividade onde esta o fragmento ex:

```
public void mudarFragmento(){
    //aqui dentro escreves o codigo que precisas, neste caso escreves o codigo para fazer o replace do fragmento
}
```

3ºDentro do fragmento, no OnClick() do butao chamas essa funcao ex:

```
((NomeDaTuaAtividade)VariavelQueRecebesteComAAtividade).mudarFragmento();
```

Achob que isto deve fazer o trabalho :) Se nao perceberes alguma coisa diz